# Can't set default page on Azure Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I published an Asp.Net web app on Azure website from Visual Studio and I can't manage setting a default page.

I have added this to web.config

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="Default.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

I left only the "Default.aspx" on Azure control panel in Default Documents.

But when typing a hostname in address bar, I still get "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable".

How can I do it properly?
Thanks

Comment: Are these tags within System.web or System.webserver?

Comment: System.webserver, of course.

Comment: Type clear like this <clear/> . I know it seems trvial but in a similar question this works

Comment: Thanks, Doesn't work either... I also tried adding enabled="true" to defaultDocument.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the path e.x ~/Default.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried changing the path, it doesn't work..

Comment: stupid question, but when you call http://yourdomain.azurewebsites.net/Default.aspx does it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a website on azure I've chosen Asp.net Emply Website and the Default page (of my own) simply doesn't work there. Then I have created by an option of 'Quick Create' and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Go to App_Start\RouteConfig.cs and edit the rule properly. Or just delete them.